# How do I use HTTP Basic Auth with http-client?

Tags: http, basic-authentication, chicken-scheme

I want to use [http-client](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/http-client) to make an HTTP request equivalent to:

```bash
curl -u 'user:pass' 'https://api.example.net/a/b/c'
```

I have read the docs for http-client, as well as for [intarweb](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/intarweb) and [uri-common](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/uri-common), but I am still unsure of how to achieve this.

I can see that it's possible to set a username and password with `make-uri`, but I'm not sure if that's the best option.

I'm open to multiple solutions if there is more than one way to do it, but an idiomatic answer is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define user "user")
(define pass "pass")

(determine-username/password
 (lambda (uri realm)
   (values user pass)))
```

See https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/http-client#authentication-support for the technical details.

Comment: As the docs say, "the default value is a procedure which extracts the username and password components from the URI", so setting the password with make-uri is definitely suppoted and probably the simplest way in general. This is why `with-input-from-request` and friends accept either a string, an URI object or a request - you pass in the simplest thing that can work.

Comment: @sjamaan maybe you could post that as a 2nd answer if you have the spare time.

Comment: OK, I've done that now

Answer (score 2):

As the docs say,

> the default value is a procedure which extracts the username and password components from the URI"

So, setting the password with `make-uri` is definitely supported and probably the simplest way in general. This is why `with-input-from-request` and friends accept either a string, an URI object or a request - you pass in the simplest thing that can work.